# How do I turn a 1-dimensional array into a double/float/int class value

Tags: arrays, integer, double, built-in

When I deal with array operations I always end up with numpy elements (imported as `np`) like:`(np.array([1]),)` or `[np.array([1]),]`. How can I transform them into  *regular* double or int values?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution:

- `(np.array([1]),)`  can be simplified with `(np.array([1]),)[0][0]`
- `[np.array([1]),]` the same: `[np.array([1]),][0][0]`

The relative outputs are:

- `1`
- `1`